# Use Permutation in Equation (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, permutation, equation

folks!
            I am looking for some help in writing a C++ code. The problem is stated below:

```
            I have an equation 
            x = (A-a[i]) + (B-b[j]) + (C-c[k]) + (D-d[l]) 
            Now (i,j,k,l) can be any permutation of (0,1,2,3) (i.e. 24 possibilities).
```

And need to check for all 24 possibilities to find the smallest value of x.
How can I do that?
PS. I am very new in C++
Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `A`, `B`, `C` or `D`?  What have you tried?

Comment: OK, you've explained what `a,b,c,d` are, now what are `A,B,C and D`?

Comment: A, B,C, D are fixed

Comment: You could start with [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) and remember, the data needs to be sorted first.

Comment: Hi sorry I posted it worngly...

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like:

```
template <typename F>
auto get_permutation_min(F f, std::vector<int> args)
{
    std::sort(args.begin(), args.end());
    auto m = f(args);
    do {
        m = std::min(m, f(args));
    } while (std::next_permutation(args.begin(), args.end()));
    return m;
}
```

And then

```
auto m = get_permutation_min(
    [&](const auto& v){
        return (A - a[v[0]]) + (B - b[v[1]]) + (C - c[v[2]]) + (D - d[v[3]]);
    },
    {0, 1, 2, 3});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double x = 0;
   for(int i1=0;i1<4;i1++)
           {
        for(int i2=0;i2<4;i2++)
             {
           for(int i3=0;i3<4;i3++)
              {
             for(int i4=0;i4<4;i4++)
                {
                 if((i1!=i2) && (i1!=i3) && (i1!=i4) && (i2!=i3) && (i2!=i4) && (i3!=i4))
                 {

                  x = (A-a[i1]) + (B-b[i2]) + (C-c[i3]) + (D-d[i4]);
                    cout << "value"<< x<< endl;
                 }

                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Comment: Tried this one...